# How can one specify trusted servers to send XSFR tokens to in Angular $http?

Tags: angularjs

I need a clean way to specify header data like XSFR tokens and authorization stuff in $http.

Something like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common["Auth_token"] = token;
```

But then all requests, also to other domains are populated with this header. Then, this fix came, that made sure only same domain received this header.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1096

Now I'm left with the problem that my server is on another domain (api.example.com), and only this, or other whitelisted servers should get specific headers.

I would love to be able to specify domains for which some headers are targeted for.

```
$http.defaults.headers.['api.trusted.com']['Auth_token'] = token;
```

Or similar. Have anyone else solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of AngularJS you could use freshly-introduced request interceptors to achieve desired results.

Comment: Oh, indeed! I've already played around with it without realizing the use for it in this regard. Will look this up and post an example here if you don't beat me to it, later today. Thanks! :D

Comment: $httpProvider.requestInterceptors.push( fn ) to the rescue!